# Linking another C file containing array definition for module

Tags: c, linux, makefile, usb, linux-device-driver

I wrote a Linux USB driver for my customized board, say the file name is usb_test.c. This driver has the capability to flash the firmware on the microcontroller.

The firmware is stored in an array .. Here comes two files ( app.h and app.c )

app.h

```
#define PIC_APPSECTOR_START_ADDRESS   0x700
#define PIC_APPSECTOR_SIZE            0x900

#define PIC_APPSECTOR_CURRENT_VERSION 0x5

extern const unsigned char ucPICAppsectorFirmware[];
```

app.c

```
#include "app.h"

const unsigned char ucPICAppsectorFirmware[] =
{
  0x93,0x2b,0xff,0x3f, 0xff,0x3f,0xff,0x3f, // Address 0x0700
  0x83,0x31,0x27,0x00, 0x93,0x1e,0x8e,0x2b, // Address 0x0708
  0x20,0x00,0x8e,0x16, 0x4b,0x08,0x95,0x00, // Address 0x0710
  0x27,0x00,0x93,0x12, 0x0b,0x1d,0x09,0x00, // Address 0x0718
  0x40,0x26,0x0b,0x11, 0x09,0x00,0x94,0x2b, // Address 0x0720
  0x22,0x30,0x84,0x00, 0x00,0x30,0x85,0x00, // Address 0x0728
  0x2d,0x30,
};
```

I want to access the ucPICAppsectorFirmware[] from the usb_test.c and perform flashing. So, I added `#include "app.h"` in usb_test.c

In kernel module Makefile, I added the following:

```
obj-m += usb_test.o
usb_test-objs := app.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

While compiling the module running "make" command didn't gave me error, but the probe function is not getting called. But when I remove the " usb_test-objs := app.o" from the Makefile, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: "ucPICAppsectorFirmware" [USB_Driver/usb_test.ko] undefined!
```

How to resolve this issue. I can copy the array into app.h and it works. But I want a solution which works with array present in app.c and not in app.h

Comment: In `app.c` explicitly mark the array as extern: `extern unsigned char ucPICAppsectorFirmware[] = {...};`. I'm guessing the const-ness of the array is making it a private symbol. I've seen other compilers do it, like MSVC and IBM XL C/C++. I don't recall seeing GCC do it, however.

Comment: Actually, it's a WinCE code which I am porting it to Linux

Comment: I am including app.h file in my usb_test.c which has the array marked as extern

Comment: Does `obj-m += usbtst.o` followed by `usbtst-objs = usb_test.o app.o` help?